# Linux Mint Not Recognizing New External Hard Drive Properly

Tags: linux-mint, gparted, external-hdd, gnome-disks

I recently bought an external hard drive by maxone to use with a Mac that I have. The instructions that I got with it was to connect it to a Windows PC and format it before I can use it with a Mac, but since I only have a Linux machine available I was hoping to be able to format it from Linux.
I have encountered similar problems some years ago but ended up finding a Windows PC to solve it. I was surprised to not find forum posts that helped me resolve it but I searched and the few things that were similar that I found were not solved, others had minor differences than my case, maybe I just didn't understand some of them properly.

### My System

Linux Mint 20.04
Toshiba Satelite laptop with the hard drive connected to the USB 3.0 connection.
`uname -a` results:
`Linux 5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 02:35:03 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

### The Problem + What I tried

When I connect the hard drive I can see it turns on and feel it spinning.
In the Linux Mint settings under "Disks" I can see a new hard drive pop up as "Maxone USB 3.0". The "Volume" section says "No Media" and appears as /dev/sdc. The the gears button has everything greyed out (including the formatting option" except for "Edit mount options" which use defaults.
I can see in the terminal that /dev/sdc exists. It does not appear under in /proc/partitions though.
`fdisk -l` does not recognize the disk at all.
I tried using Gparted but it did not recognize the hard drive either.
`lsusb` did find:
`Bus 004 Device 005: ID 152d:0583 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. Maxone`
`sudo lshw -c disk` finds:

```
 *-disk
   description: SCSI Disk
   product: USB 3.0
   vendor: Maxone
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@7:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sdc
   version: 0209
   serial: DD564198838A2
   configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

When I connect the hard drive I see in `dmesg` the following:

```
[205381.443074] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[205381.464174] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0583, bcdDevice= 2.09
[205381.464179] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[205381.464183] usb 4-1: Product: Maxone
[205381.464186] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Maxone
[205381.464188] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000020200909
[205381.470699] scsi host7: uas
[205381.472216] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Maxone   USB 3.0          0209 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[205381.473026] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
```

Given all of this I could not figure out a way to format the hard drive, as I do not have a partition to format or a way to initialize the drive (that I can tell at least).

#### Edit

As per the comments I ran some more commands that unfortunately did not work and here are the results:
`sudo mkfs -t fat /dev/sdc`:

```
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
attribute "partition" not found
mkfs.fat: unable to discover size of /dev/sdc
```

`sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc`:

```
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
mkfs.ext4: Device size reported to be zero.  Invalid partition specified, or
partition table wasn't reread after running fdisk, due to a modified partition being busy and in use.  You may need to reboot to
re-read your partition table.
```

`sudo echo , | sudo sfdisk /dev/sdc`:

```
sfdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: No such file or directory
```

(this is despite /dev/sdc existing (I can see it using `ls`)

### Final Questions

Is the only way to initialize and format a newly bought external hard drive that was intended for Windows in Windows itself? Is there no way to do this on Linux?

What causes the drive to be recognized as /dev/sdc but at the same time not be registered by fdisk? Is this because of the filesystem type on it? Shouldn't fdisk be able to nuke and re-initialize a hard drive no matter what?

Thank you for your time and any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: since you don't seem to be afraid of the command line, run `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc` to create a filesystem on the drive. Optionally, create a partition first: `echo , | sfdisk /dev/sdc`, then create the filesystem on /dev/sdc1.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately both these commands did not work, I will update my original post with the results as some outputs are long

Comment: Since it's a USB drive, it can change  it's identity. Try "fdisk -l" and look for a drive with the proper size, Also, I would use "sudo mkfs.vfat  /dev/sdX" where you have to determine the value of X. And last but not least, when you  are done creating the filesystem, uplug it, and plug it in again, and it should mount itself automatically under "/media/<userid>/<some random string>". Then later, you can clean it up and make it do what you want. Note of this will work if the drive is already mounted.

Comment: Thanks fot the comment! "fdisk -l" like all the other fdisk commands that I ran does not find the hard drive at all. the mkfs command you gave gives the same as the other ones I ran, which is "mkfs.vfat: unable to discover size of /dev/sdc", do you have any other ideas?